# How to write CSV data to dictionary (or better way to handle situation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I'm attempting to write data from a CSV file to a python dictionary. I'm able to access the data I need but I'm coming up blank on how to input into a dictionary. This data is eventually going to be re-written to a new CSV file for import into a different system.

In the below code, you'll see that the eventual target CSV file has 2 sets of headers. They're being written with writerow() first. The relevant lines are commented out to not write them each time I test-run the script.

The print statements in `with open(bccsv, newline='') as csvfile:` all work when uncommented.

`testdict.update("sonum": row['Order ID'])` is my attempt to write the first key-pair but it throws a syntax error at the colon.

```
import csv

bccsv = "order.csv"
fbcsv = "fbcsv.csv"
testdict = {"ordertype": "SO"}
#header1 = ["Flag","SONum","Status","CustomerName","CustomerContact","BillToName","BillToAddress","BillToCity","BillToState","BillToZip","BillToCountry","ShipToName","ShipToAddress","ShipToCity","ShipToState","ShipToZip","ShipToCountry","ShipToResidential","CarrierName","TaxRateName","PriorityId","PONum","VendorPONum","Date","Salesman","ShippingTerms","PaymentTerms","FOB","Note","QuickBooksClassName","LocationGroupName","OrderDateScheduled","URL","CarrierService","DateExpired","Phone,Email","Category","CF-Credit Key Approval ID","CarrierName","CF-Skynamo Comments"]
#header2 = ["Flag","SOItemTypeID","ProductNumber","ProductDescription","ProductQuantity","UOM","ProductPrice","Taxable","TaxCode","Note","ItemQuickBooksClassName","ItemDateScheduled","ShowItem","KitItem","RevisionLevel","CustomerPartNumber"]

#write first header row to CSV
#with open(fbcsv, "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    #wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    #wr.writerow(header1)

#write second header row to CSV
#with open(fbcsv, "a", newline="") as csvfile:
    #wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    #wr.writerow(header2)


#PRINT WORKING - .update does not work
with open(bccsv, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        testdict.update("sonum": row['Order ID'])
        #print(row['Order ID'])
        #print(row['Billing Company'])
        #print(row['Customer Email'])
        #print(row['Customer Phone'])
        #print(row['Order Date'])
        #print(row['Ship Method'])
        #print(row['Billing Street 1'])
        #print(row['Billing Suburb'])
        #print(row['Billing State'])
        #print(row['Billing Zip'])
        #print(row['Billing Country'])
        #print(row['Billing Location Group'])
        #print(row['Billing koi_rep'])
        #print(row['Product Details'])
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your input

Comment: I think you need curly braces in the update `testdict.update({"sonum": row['Order ID']})`

Comment: Or, better yet, `testdict['sonum'] = row['Order ID']`.

Comment: @HaiVu I intentionally left out the input because there's information that shouldn't be shared publicly. The input is a BigCommerce Order Export. https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Importing-Exporting-Orders?language=en_US#exportable-fields

Comment: @ChrisCharley I'll give your suggestions a try. Thank you!

Your suggestion worked. Thank you!

Comment: You are updating the key `sonum` with a new value each time through the loop. In the end the, `sonum` entry in the dict will only have the last `row['Order ID']` value.

Comment: @ChrisCharley I'm only expecting to use this with single datasets and therefore only 1 sonum per run of the script. The CSVs only contain a single header row and a single data row.

Comment: @TimRoberts Your suggestion also worked and is less code.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

dictionary`.update` requires a dictionary, you a missing the curly braces in `testdict.update("sonum": row['Order ID'])`.

```py
import csv


csv_file = """\
Order ID,Total
X123456,420.69
"""

testdict = {"ordertype": "SO"}

data = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file.splitlines()))

print(data) # [{'Order ID': 'X123456', 'Total': '420.69'}]

for row in data:
    testdict.update({"sonum": row["Order ID"]})
    # or
    testdict["total"] = row["Total"]

print(testdict) # {'ordertype': 'SO', 'sonum': 'X123456', 'total': '420.69'}
```

Comment: Hi Richard. Thank you for the response. When I implement the data variable as you have, it prints an empty list. Any idea why that is? I like the approach.